# HtmlRender How import css and Jquery library

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, html-rendering

I want to convert HTML to Image with [HtmlRender](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer)

first I read the HTML document

```
string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Jora\Desktop\test.html");
```

then I create the image from this HTML and save it

```
      var image = HtmlRender.RenderToImage(html);
image.Save(@"C:\test\Test_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Image is created, but styles and Jquery library its not loaded and styles not applied

Examples of css and jquery import in html document:

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/jquery/jquery.js"
                                              type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://example.com/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
                                              type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
        .className{margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 20px}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          var contentHeight = jQuery(".div_info").height();
          var leftContainer = jQuery(".section-info");
          leftContainer.css('height', contentHeight);
     });// onready end
  </script>
```

How import and set the styles and JQyery code to this Image Convert?

Comment: I don't think JavaScript is supported. Check out the FAQ: https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation